# koffi nested struct arrays

Tags: c++, node.js, typescript

I'm Using koffi 2.4.2 on a node.js app from [koffi.dev](https://koffi.dev) and things have been as easy as pie until now. I have a native C++ library method that takes a parameter struct defined as follows:

**mylib.h**

```
typedef int token;

typedef struct token_data {
    token id; 
    float logit;    
    float p;        
} token_data;

typedef struct token_data_array {
    token_data * data;
    size_t size;
    bool sorted;
} token_data_array;
```

I'm having trouble getting the koffi library to accept this parameter.

**mylib.cpp**

```
void sample(token_data_array * tokens)
```

My current setup is defined so:

**TypeScript Node.js file**

```
export const TokenDataArrayType = koffi.struct('token_data_array', {
    data: koffi.array(koffi.struct({
        id: 'int32',
        logit: 'float32',     
        p: 'float32'         
    }), 32000, 'Array'),
    size: 'int32',
    sorted: 'bool'
});
const myLib = koffi.load(libLocation);
const sample = myLib.func('sample', 'uint32',[TokenDataArrayType])
sample(/* object is built elsewhere */)
```

I have tried various combinations, including using **koffee.inout(koffi.pointer(TokenDataArrayType, 1))** as the input param for the lib, removing **koffi.array** from the nested attribute data, and other approaches that came to mind, but nothing has worked.

Either I get an error from the koffi library or my app crashes without any additional logs.

Is there anyone who has experience with this library and can provide some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Types made with `koffi.array()` are for fixed C arrays, but in this case `token_data_array` takes a pointer and a size and does not embed a fixed array.

In addition, your sample function takes a pointer to a `token_data_array` value, and it seems it changes the content so you have to use `koffi.inout()` on the pointer argument.

Something like this should work:

```js
const TokenDataType = koffi.struct('token_data', {
    id: 'int',
    logit: 'float',
    p: 'float'
});
export const TokenDataArrayType = koffi.struct('token_data_array', {
    data: koffi.pointer(TokenDataType),
    size: 'size_t',
    sorted: 'bool'
});

const myLib = koffi.load(libLocation);

const sample = myLib.func('sample', 'void', [koffi.inout(koffi.pointer(TokenDataArrayType))]);

// Example array with 2 tokens
const tokens = [
    { id: 1, logit: -0,405, p: 0.4 },
    { id: 2, logit: -0,847, p: 0.3 }
];

const data = {
    data: tokens,
    size: tokens.length,
    sorted: false
};

sample(data);

// Now access tokens and look at the modified data :)
```