# Koffi - Passing Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, node.js, typescript

I'm using [Koffi.dev](https://koffi.dev/) and I'm trying to get a multidimensional array to be accepted as a parameter. I've taken a look at this SO post, but it seems to have confused, rather than helped:

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446673/koffi-nested-struct-arrays)

My parameter is defined in the DLL as follows:

```
unsigned char myVar[][128]
```

I have created a suitable array for holding the data as follows:

```
const myBuf = new Array(128).fill(0).map(
    () => new Array(128).fill(0));
```

How would I
a) create the definition for the library call (I'm not sure using koffi.struct is required or correct). I tried many combinations of pointer/struct to no real change.

b) Can I use myBuf as the parameter when I actually call the library or do I need something else? The buffer is filled in by the library so it does need to be some sort of inout parameter.

Comment: When you "mark down", please indicate why. I've no idea right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering the answer is as follows.

First of all define the structure:

```
  const innerArray = koffi.struct('innerArray', {
    buffer: koffi.array('uchar', 128, 'Array')
  });
  const outerArray = koffi.struct('outerArray', {
    buffer: koffi.array(innerArray, 128, 'Array')
  });
```

You can use outArray in the call:

```
koffi.inout(koffi.pointer(outerArray))
```

When you call the library just provide an allocated buffer of 16K:

```
 private myBuf  = {buffer: Buffer.alloc(16384)};
```

The buffer will be filled in by the DLL as expected.

```
this.libCall(myBuf);

// Use myBuf
```